# Traversing negative, positive numbers in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I want to call a function in C++.

```
 check(T);
```

in a sequence :

```
check(T);  
check(T-1);
check(T+1);
check(T-2);
check(T+2);
```

I want to do it in a loop, as the combinations may increase in future.

Comment: Tell more about future combinations.

Comment: (T-9987)....(T-6379)(T+6379) .....(T+9987)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows one of approaches

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < N; i += j ^= 1 )
    {
        std::cout << ( j == 0 ? i : -i ) << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0
-1
1
-2
2
-3
3
-4
4
-5
5
-6
6
-7
7
-8
8
-9
9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
check(T);

for(int i=1; i<N; i++)
{
    check(T-i);
    check(T+i);
}
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: More or less yes, but it's Increasing the no of lines of code. The loop can be multiple but check(T) call shouldn't be.

Comment: Tell more about other combinations, your Q is not clear

Answer (score 0):

If the combinations to be tested can be described by a (indexed) sequence you can implement it in a function.
For your example above this would be:

```
int sequence(int i) 
{
if(i % 2 != 0)
     return i - (i/2);
else
     return -(i-(i/2));
}

check(T)
for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    check(T-sequence(i));
}
```

If they aren't in a simply definable order you may save all combinatations in a datastructure (e.g. a vector) and just traverse it in a for loop.